# dataTransfer.getData undefined error on 'drop' event.

Tags: angularjs, html, drag-and-drop

I'm tryin to implement Drag & Drop using AngularJS through directives.

here's what I'm trying to do :

[`codePen`](http://codepen.io/PriyankaCodes/pen/NAVkAj)

But I'm getting a 'getData' undefined error.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I kind of figured out what was happening. I'll try my best to explain as succinctly as possible, but this is only an explanation of what I learnt about the 'event' object. Please research on your own more detailed information.

The problem was not assigning the correct 'event' object in the 'drag' and 'drop' directives. So, when you start dragging an element, an 'event' is fired and an 'event' object is created, which has all the related information including the 'type' of the event and this info is located in an object called 'original Event'.

It is this 'original event' object that these 'dragstart' and 'drop' events use to communicate. Hence, it is this object that has to be used to 'setData' in the 'drag' directive and 'getData' in the 'drop' directive.

Like this :

```js
app.directive('myDrag', function(dragevent){
      
  return function(scope, attr, elem){
    
    elem.on('dragstart', function(dragevent){
      
       dragevent = event.originalEvent || event;
               dragevent.dataTransfer.setData('text',dragevent.target.id);
       
     }
   }         
            
  });
        


 app.directive('myDrop', function(dropevent){
      
      return function(scope, attr, elem){
        
        elem.on('dragover', function(event){
          event.originalEvent.preventDefault();
        }
        
        elem.on('drop', function(dropevent){
        
          dropevent = event.originalEvent || event;
      
          var data = dropevent.dataTransfer.getData('text');
        
          console.log(data); //Should output the id of the element dragged
        }
     }
       
});
```

I also have a working example here :

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/PriyankaCodes/pen/NAVkAj)

Once again, this is my understanding. Anyone with more indepth knowledge of how this works, please feel free to correct me or answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can store something in the dragStartEvent and get it from the droppedEvent.

I would store the value in a service. 
This should look like

```
app.service('dragService', function(){
var currentId;
function setDragItemId(id){
  currentId=id;
 }
function getDragItemId(){
  return currentId;
}
 return{
  setDragItemId : setDragItemId,
  getDragItemId: getDragItemId
 }
})
```

and should be used like

```
app.directive('dndDragStart', function(dragService){

return{
restrict: 'A',
link :function(scope, elem, attr){

  elem.on('dragstart', function(event){
    console.log(event.target.id +"start");
    event = event.originalEvent || event;
     event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    dragService.setDragItemId(event.target.id);   //here you go
  });     
 } 
};
});
```

get it from the service should be self-explanatory

Comment: Your solution works. But, dataTransfer values can be accessed from 'drop' events ( and only in 'drop' events) as far as my knowledge goes. You can  see this example: [https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/blob/master/angular-drag-and-drop-lists.js]. The 'text' value that has been set in 'dragstart' event is accessed from the 'drop' event in another direcitve.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, thank you for the information. 
I am glad it works.